# Spacing and centering bootstrap navbar items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am making an eCommerce website and want these three elements on my navbar: Logo on the left, the product categories in the middle, and the avatar on the right.  I am trying to put the categories in the middle, but they just aren't moving.  They are fixed next to the avatar.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <%= link_to "Diary", "#", class: "nav-link" %>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <%= link_to "Pen", "#", class: "nav-link" %>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <%= link_to "Tape", "#", class: "nav-link" %>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

I am trying text-align center, giving the UL a new class, inline-block, but nothing is working.  I am not sure where to give a new class or where to change the options.  Can I center it via the ul class or do I need to go into the div holding all the elements?  I only want to center the above items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flex-box:

```css
.navbar-nav {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
 }
```

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <%= link_to "Diary", "#", class: "nav-link" %>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <%= link_to "Pen", "#", class: "nav-link" %>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <%= link_to "Tape", "#", class: "nav-link" %>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or, if you use bootstrap 4, you can add the following classes: `d-flex justify-content-between`

Answer (score 0):

One of solution it's to create own nav like that. I am not working with bootstrap so I have provided simple snipp below.

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

nav .logo {
  width: 20%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}

nav .navigation {
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

nav .navigation a {
  padding: 0 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

nav .user {
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

nav .user a {
  padding: 0 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

nav .user-avatar {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
  <div class="navigation">
    <a href="#">LINK</a>
    <a href="#">LINK</a>
    <a href="#">LINK</a>
    <a href="#">LINK</a>
    <a href="#">LINK</a>
  </div>
  <div class="user">
    <a href="#">ICON</a>
    <a href="#">ICON</a>
    <div class="user-avatar"></div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: It didn't work.  It doesn't budge at all.  The main div that houses the entire nav bar uses space-between.  The secondary dive where my links are placed in uses flex-grow: 0.  I am not sure if I should change these or not.  If I add a class to my ul list it doesn't seem to change anything.